# CSRF AngularJS SPA and WEB API

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am working on AngularJS SPA and WebApi and i am implementing CSRF in my POST/PUT/DELETE request, Again all my views are html templates not MVC views at all, for CSRF i am generating cookie almost the way this example http://www.cmsmatrix.org/matrix/cms-matrix/sitefinity is, My question is this approach is perfect or i need to generate 2 cookies one is Token cookie and other is form cookie as here http://ericpanorel.net/2013/07/28/spa-authentication-and-csrf-mvc4-antiforgery-implementation/ but this link is with MVC , webapi and angular and its layout page is chtml and in my case my shell page is index.html

Please explain?

Thanks

Comment: Not clear at all what you are asking. For something like csrf you should be as specific as you can. HTML templates aren't a major concern, it's really more critical for any CRUD operations users would be making

Comment: yes it is for all POST or PUT but my question is do we need 2 type of cookies one is Token cookie and other is FormCookie as here http://ericpanorel.net/2013/07/28/spa-authentication-and-csrf-mvc4-antiforgery-implementation/ but i am not using MVC views at all, In your link you are only using one cookie it it really safe or is this recommended practice for CSRF in Angular SPA app with WebApi

Comment: charlietfl i updated my question please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out answer, Actually we manually set XSRF-TOKEN on web API which is not httponly because AngularJS access automatically this token and add in response header X-XSRF-TOKEN against, in asp.net case this token is usually in hidden field which we pick from hidden field and send back with every request.